# Get information from Firebase Database without autoID

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

Currently, I'm getting information from my Firebase Database like the following:

```
 Database.database().reference().child("users/BA917746-F5BE-4FA4-B23E-C998F4118CCE").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
              
            let dict = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]
                            
            self.name = dict["name"] as! String
```

This is my JSON tree:

[image]

The information is being fetched where it's trying to unpack a random ID under the 'BA9...' part. How do I gather information from directly under the BA9 part with another autoID inside of it? Thank you.

Comment: Everything under "BA9..." is going to be in the `snapshot` you received.  Use its api to dig into the child values. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/DataSnapshot

Comment: @DougStevenson Right, but how would that be done with my example?

Comment: Your example doesn't show what that other auto ID is. In any case, the API provided by the snapshot will let you get it.

Comment: Okay, my question is how do I "get it" from the code I have? I understand the snapshot provides it I'm just not entirely sure how. Thank you for your responses.

Comment: The DataSnapshot object has properties and methods that let you discover and access the child names and values.  Use the API documentation that I linked.

Comment: Can you give me an example specifically for my work? The documentation you provided is not providing me with specific answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the confusion stems from the fact that you are observing `.childAdded`. Since you're only observing one node/entity, you'll want to observe `.value` instead:

```
Database.database().reference()
    .child("users/BA917746-F5BE-4FA4-B23E-C998F4118CCE")
    .observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
          
        let dict = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]
                        
        self.name = dict["name"] as! String
```

---

If you we're to observe the entire `users` node, that's when you'd either use `.childAdded` or loop over the child nodes of the snapshot.